# MPMoviePlayerController play video second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayer

I need to have the possibility to play more than one video in an app.

Unfortunately, the second time I press play, video appears blinking.

I use only this code for playing vide

> NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"]] autorelease];
>
> MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
>
> mp.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
>
> [mp play];
>
> moviePlayer = mp;
>
> [mp release];

Can anyone tell me where can be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:** It seems that the Apple [MoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798) example has the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also do it by setting the initial playback time to -1.0 before calling the play function

```
mp.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
```

Put this code before ur play method is called.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved it by using the notification system to execute a callback after the MPMoviePlayerController finishes playing, and releasing the player object there.

Add a notification before you play the movie:

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"]] autorelease];

MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

mp.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;

//***Add this line***
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mp];

[mp play];
```

Then add the callback method,

```
-(void)myMovieFinished:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
    [moviePlayer release];
}
```

Comment: Still having the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure the original movieplayercontroller isn't being retained somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the only solution is... to make the app for 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I also find run on the OS 3.1 or later version of simulator can be played well.It won't appears blinking.But when I add

```
initialPlaybackTime = -1.0
```

it will also play well on OS 3.0.